# JQuery round up the length of a result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code:

```
$("#total_percentage").text(
    (parseInt($("#capacity").text(), 10) / parseInt($("#total").text(), 10))
);
```

My problem is that #total_percentage sometimes gives a long result.

e.g: 2.33333333333

Is there a way to setting it so it rounds up / shows only max of 2 digits?

for example: 2 or 10

Comment: This is overkill for a small problem, but I highly recommend sugarjs: http://sugarjs.com/

Comment: Are you asking about showing two digits AFTER the decimal?  In your example:  `2.33`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round up use the Javascript Math library.

```
$("#total_percentage").text(
    (Math.ceil(parseInt($("#capacity").text(), 10) / parseInt($("#total").text(), 10)))
);
```

Comment: Math.ceil ALWAYS rounds up (2.33333 would show 3, not 2).  Just making sure that's OK... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed()`:

```
$("#total_percentage").text(
    (parseInt($("#capacity").text(), 10) / parseInt($("#total").text(), 10)).toFixed(2)
);
```

References:

- [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display two digits *to the right of the decimal*, `Math.toFixed` is the solution:

```
(2.33333333).toFixed(2) === "2.33"
```

Note that this results in a string, not a number. If you want to display 2 digits *total*, `Math.toPrecision` is what you want:

```
(2.33333333).toPrecision(2) === "2.3"
```

Again, this results in a string. To get back to a number (if desired), you can use `parseFloat`.

A final note that both these functions will also round your number. For example:

```
(1.23456).toPrecision(4) === "1.235"
```

If you want to truncate your number without rounding, you can write a function like this:

```
function truncate(num,precision) {
    var muldiv = Math.pow(10,precision-1);
    return Math.floor(num * muldiv) / muldiv;
}

truncate(1.23456,4) === 1.234
```

Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating each method:

[**---jsFiddle DEMO---**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/sa5FL/)